# App imported into Android Studio from Eclipse, gradle errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, gradle

```
`com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2`
```

Also, there's a compile error that says

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode;","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)","sources":[{}]}
```

I attempted to import a project from Eclipse into Android Studio but it returned a strange error. Here's one gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

and here's another gradle, named 'app'

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.thisisanapp"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.8.2.jar')
}
```

and another gradle named 'settings.gradle'

```
include ':app'
```

This app uses the Google Maps library, as well as some Parse. How do I configure Android Studio to run the app?

Comment: There should be more in your Gradle Console about what exactly the problem is. Scan upwards from the bottom until you run into the compile error or whatever.

Comment: I added it. I don't know what to do though, since neither of those files are in my actual app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove:

```
compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
```

from your `dependencies` closure, and delete the JAR. Stick with the artifact (`'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'`), though you may wish to go with something a bit more fine-grained and with an actual version number. See [the Play Services SDK setup documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup), particularly the "Selectively compiling APIs into your executable" section.